# GCP: Can we modify primary key of an existing table in spanner

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I want to modify Primary key of an existing Table in Spanner from Col1 to combination of Col1 and Col2. Is it possible to do it in Spanner?

This option is not available in Console. Maybe it can be done with a script!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCP Team responded below:

- Only way to do it now is to recreate database using Import/Export functionality
- Feature request is raised on Spanner backlog (no ETA): https://issuetracker.google.com/135719292

Answer (score 4):

> The keys of a table can't change; you can't add a key column to an existing table or remove a key column from an existing table.

[Schema and data model | Cloud Spanner Documentation | Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/schema-and-data-model#notes_about_key_columns)

Comment: So what is the option for same in Spanner if we have change in business requirement? Are we suppose to create a new Table and move data into it. Seems strange that their is no good way of handling it as we can't know all requirements in advance!

Comment: @Ayush, that is correct. Feel free to file a feature request to the team here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=190851&template=1163127

Comment: Thanks, I have added a support ticket to GCP under our project. Will let everyone know if I get an update from GCP product team.